# Can you use Javascript popups in js2py

Tags: javascript, python

I want to create a function in python that will create a javascript `confirm()` popup window when called, and return the user input.  I need this as a tool for the website I'm creating (I'm using Django so most of my 'back end' code is in python).

So far I've discovered `js2py` as a possible solution, but I am not sure if this package works with the javascript popup functions like `confirm()` and `alert()`.

So far I've tried these approaches:

```
import js2py

def Error_Popup(message):
  retval = js2py.eval_js('var retval = confirm(message); retval')
  return retval
```

and

```
import js2py

def Error_Popup(message):
  retval = js2py.eval_js('function continue(message){var retval=confirm(message); return retval}')
  return retval
```

But I keep getting the error: `PyJsException: ReferenceError: confirm is not defined` when I run the functions.

Is possible to use `js2py` with javascript popups and if so what the correct syntax for it is?

**-- EDIT --**

Is it at all possible to create a javascript-like popup from python?  I've tried things like `easygui` but they are slow.  I would really like to have something that I can put in a python function so it interacts well with my Django website.

Comment: You can't show a confirmation box on the server. (Or perhaps you can, but it would show up on the server, not the client). Sounds like you're mixing up server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So it isn't possible to get confirmation box to show up unless I write it into a `<script>` on my html page?

Comment: Right. Otherwise, the code executes on the server.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo do you know if there is anything javascript-like that I could use?  I've tried easygui and others and they are all too slow